# Resize Primary Partition in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, root

I've set up a Ubuntu server the wrong way round. On a 2TB hard drive I gave 20GB to the root system partition and 1.8TB to home. I'd like to reverse this. I'm reading there is a tool, which may be able to do this:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda 1000000M
```

But I'm getting conflicting information as to whether this can be done while the system is running. Can anyone uncloud this?

Answer (score 1):

The `resize2fs` utility will resize the *filesystem*, but not the *partition* in which it's stored. It also won't shrink a mounted filesystem, as the first paragraph in its man page clearly states.

A better solution for you is to boot an Ubuntu desktop installer into its live CD mode and [use GParted to resize your partitions.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)